Auth in .net framework asp web forms 4.8 using google facebook twitter microsoft
i`am obligated to use aso.net web forms 4.8  to make a login and register using a form  and using google ,facebook,twitter , microsoft .
   <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="username">Username</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username"  />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="password">Password</label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"  />
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
   </form>

add the session configuartion and the user redirections
